# Text file to CSV file with header

Tags: csv, powershell, text

I have a question about a text file that I want to convert to a CSV file with headers.

The origional text file looks like this:

```
StepStartTime: 2/1/2016 12:02:03 PM
StepStopTime: 2/1/2016 12:02:06 PM
StepNumber: 1
NextStepNumber: 2
---------------------------------------------------------------
StepStartTime: 2/1/2016 12:02:06 PM
StepStopTime: 2/1/2016 12:02:07 PM
StepNumber: 2
NextStepNumber: 3
---------------------------------------------------------------
StepStartTime: 2/1/2016 12:02:07 PM
StepStopTime: 2/1/2016 12:02:08 PM
StepNumber: 3
NextStepNumber: 4
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

What I want to get is the following:

```
StepStartTime,StepStopTime,StepNumber,NextStepNumber
2/1/2016 12:02:03 PM,2/1/2016 12:02:06 PM,1,2
2/1/2016 12:02:06 PM,2/1/2016 12:02:07 PM,2,3
2/1/2016 12:02:07 PM,2/1/2016 12:02:08 PM,3,4
```

I'm trying to get it to work in PowerShell but no luck so far. I can read code on a basic level but to combine different actions by myself is one step to far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the input into a string and split it at the separating lines

```
(Get-Content 'C:\path\to\input.txt' -Raw) -split '-{63}'
```

so you get snippets like this:

```
StepStartTime: 2/1/2016 12:02:07 PM
StepStopTime: 2/1/2016 12:02:08 PM
StepNumber: 3
NextStepNumber: 4
```

Change the colons into `=` characters, so you can convert the snippets to hashtables via [`ConvertFrom-StringData`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849900.aspx):

```
$snippet -replace ': ', '=' | ConvertFrom-StringData
```

Which will give you something like this for each snippet:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
StepStopTime                   2/1/2016 12:02:08 PM
StepNumber                     3
NextStepNumber                 4
StepStartTime                  2/1/2016 12:02:07 PM
```

Create custom objects from the hashtables:

```
New-Object -Type PSObject -Property $hashtable
```

to get a format that you can export to a CSV:

```
StepStopTime           StepNumber   NextStepNumber   StepStartTime
------------           ----------   --------------   -------------
2/1/2016 12:02:08 PM   3            4                2/1/2016 12:02:07 PM
```

---

Full code:

```
(Get-Content 'C:\path\to\input.txt' -Raw) -split '-{63}' | Where-Object {
  $_.Trim()
} | ForEach-Object {
  $props = $_.Trim() -replace ': ', '=' | ConvertFrom-StringData
  New-Object -Type PSObject -Property $props
} | Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\output.csv' -NoType
```

---

**Note:** If you're still using PowerShell v2 you need to replace

```
Get-Content 'C:\path\to\input.txt' -Raw
```

with something like

```
Get-Content 'C:\path\to\input.txt' | Out-String
```

to get the content of the file as a single string. The parameter `-Raw` isn't available prior to PowerShell v3.

Comment: If I use the code as above than I only get the StepStartTime value as Column. Other column I don't see. the convert from stringData seems like not working well? 

Until the replace works fine as aspect.

thanks in advanced!

Comment: You're either using PowerShell v2 or you omitted the parameter `-Raw` when reading the input file. For PowerShell v2 pipe the `Get-Content` output throught `Out-String` (`(Get-Content 'C:\path\to\input.txt' | Out-String) ...`), otherwise add the missing parameter.